# How to ignore "Import with 'xxx' " in SLComposeViewController

Tags: swift, swift3, slcomposeviewcontroller

I make a `SLComposeViewController` everything works fine until I want to share my Image, there's alot things to click including " import to whatsapp, import to Instagram " and etc.

If I clicked on this my apps will stuck. So I want to exclude all this import things. 
The question is how can I ? because in `UIActivityType.` there's no choice of exclude this module

```
func shareQR(){        
    if filename != nil {
        let imageToShare = [ filename ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop ]

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
    } 
}
```

**EDIT IMAGE**

[image]

There's bunch of thing that useless here like "Copy to" & "Import with"
I just need like "Instagram" "Whatsapp" and etc.

I need to exclude all of this because it's useless and if this icon clicked will freeze my apps.

Comment: Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: as you told 'freezing app' you need to figure out your code.It's working fine(dismissing) as i tested.

Comment: well that's a second problem, the main problem is I don't need that tho showed up. how to exclude that @Jack

Comment: Can you put some of sharing code ?

Comment: what part of specific code sir ? isn't the code I give already call the SLComposerViewController. nothing else

Comment: After `UIActivityViewController` open, when you tap on any activity items `UIActivityViewController ` will dismiss(`dismissViewController(animated:true)`) hence perhaps you need to check with your current as well as previous viewcontroller.

Comment: Is it needed ? because I dont have any of that like `(dismissViewController(animated:true)` maybe I'm missing something here, because the only code about UIActivityViewController only that code

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS API of `UIActivityViewController`

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open class UIActivityViewController : UIViewController {


    public init(activityItems: [Any], applicationActivities: [UIActivity]?)


    @available(iOS, introduced: 6.0, deprecated: 8.0, message: "Use completionWithItemsHandler instead.")
    open var completionHandler: UIKit.UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler? // set to nil after call

    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    open var completionWithItemsHandler: UIKit.UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler? // set to nil after call


    open var excludedActivityTypes: [UIActivityType]? // default is nil. activity types listed will not be displayed
}
```

There is no extra methods for excluding share activities (Which is presented on first row), Only user have choice to enable/disable by clicking More on first row then disable switch.

Comment: Only with by clicking More ? nothing else ? 
I know there's a option from `More` but not all people want to go through that. thats why

Comment: Nothing. Only user have choice to disable that. Because we really don't know which apps are installed on iPhone